# Ethernet connect and disconnect

Tags: networking, ethernet

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and after connect the ethernet cable, the system show the connected icon.

But after a few seconds, the system show the disconnect alert. Here is the log:

```
Oct 25 19:09:40 note dbus[769]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Oct 25 19:09:40 note systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Oct 25 19:09:40 note dbus[769]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Oct 25 19:09:40 note systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Oct 25 19:09:40 note nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [enp19s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Oct 25 19:09:40 note nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [enp19s0]: start running ordered scripts...
```

Runing `sudo lshw -C net`

```
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:12:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:fbb00000-fbb03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:13:00.0
       logical name: enp19s0
       version: c1
       serial: f0:4d:a2:d7:11:90
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:32 memory:fba00000-fba3ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlp18s0b1
       serial: c0:cb:38:9c:4d:f6
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=4.4.0-43-generic firmware=610.812 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: In terminal, type `sudo lshw -C net` and edit the results into your question. I want to see if you're using the r8169 driver. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema I post the result.

Comment: You're not using the driver that I suspected. Sorry. Cheers, Al